# R Use Regular Expression to capture number when sometimes the capture is at the end of the string or not

Tags: r, regex

I need to capture the numbers out of a string that come after a certain parameter name.

I have it working for most, but there is one parameter that is sometimes at the end of the string, but not always.  When using the regular expression, it seems to matter.

I've tried different things, but nothing seems to work in both cases.

```
# Regular expression to capture the digit after the phrase "AppliedWhenID="
p <- ".*&AppliedWhenID=(.\\d*)"

# Tried this, but when at end, it just grabs a blank
#p <- ".*&AppliedWhenID=(.\\d*)&.*|.*&AppliedWhenID=(.\\d*)$"

testAtEnd <- "ReportType=233&ReportConID=171&MonthQuarterYear=0TimePeriodLabel=Year%202020&AppliedWhenID=2"

testNotAtEnd <- "ReportType=233&ReportConID=171&MonthQuarterYear=0TimePeriodLabel=Year%202020&AppliedWhenID=2&AgDateTypeID=1"


# What should be returned is "2"

gsub(p, "\\1", testAtEnd) # works
gsub(p, "\\1", testNotAtEnd) # doesn't work, it captures 2 + &AgDateTypeID=1
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to use a regex? `urltools::param_get()` could be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `sub` and `gsub` *replace* the found text(s), thus, in order to *extract* a part of the input string with a capturing group + a backreference, you need to actually *match* (and consume) the whole string.

Hence, you need to match the string to the end by adding `.*` at the end of the pattern:

```r
p <- ".*&AppliedWhenID=(\\d+).*"
sub(p, "\\1", testNotAtEnd)
# => [1] "2"
sub(p, "\\1", testAtEnd)
# => [1] "2"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MdHtx7/2) and the [R online demo](https://ideone.com/nAct9a).

Note that `gsub` matches multiple occurrences, you need a single one, so it makes sense to replace `gsub` with `sub`.

*Regex details*

- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `&AppliedWhenID=` - a `&AppliedWhenID=` string
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (`\1`): one or more digits
- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the string look behind conditional "(?<=)" and `str_extract()` from the stringr library.

```
testAtEnd <- "ReportType=233&ReportConID=171&MonthQuarterYear=0TimePeriodLabel=Year%202020&AppliedWhenID=2"

testNotAtEnd <- "ReportType=233&ReportConID=171&MonthQuarterYear=0TimePeriodLabel=Year%202020&AppliedWhenID=2&AgDateTypeID=1"

p <- "(?<=AppliedWhenID=)\\d+"

# What should be returned is "2"
library(stringr)
str_extract(testAtEnd, p)
str_extract(testNotAtEnd, p)
```

Or in base R

```
p <- ".*((?<=AppliedWhenID=)\\d+).*"

gsub(p, "\\1", testAtEnd, perl=TRUE) 
gsub(p, "\\1", testNotAtEnd, perl=TRUE)
```